# How do I store the string value from input field in an empty array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, string

I'm having trouble storing input values from `<input>` tag in `HTML` into array of strings, I can't figure out how am I suppose to do that. I have an idea on how that might look like, however I still can't get it to work.

I believe that I have to use `.push()` and `.join()` method and `+=` or `+` operator, it's just I do not know where to put them.

The first thing I did was searching on Google `How to store string value from input in an array of strings?` but I only found on how to do it using `<form>` tag in `HTML` and I can't do that. I can't use the `<form>` tag.

Here's the code that I think should look like

```html
<body>
  <input type="text" id="input" />
  <button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
  <div id="placeholder"></div>
</body>
```

```js
var inputName = document.getElementById("input");
var cityArray = [""];

// This triggers immediately when the browser loads
window.onload = (
  // Pickup the string from input and add it on the previously created array
  function submit() {
    inputName.value;

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      array[i];
    }
  }
);
```

I also need a piece of code that will delete the value that was typed in a `<input>` field right after the `Submit` button is pressed, so that the user doesn't need to press `Backspace` in order to type the second input value.

Comment: You have a number of syntax errors. Please make sure your example is a [mcve].

Comment: @evolutionbox Yes, `array is not defined`, because I've typed `for` in Atom and pressed the `Tab` key. I've left that there as a "placeholder".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working code snippet.

When you click the submit button, that will call the `submit()` function. Since your array is defined to be global, you can access it within the function. You do not need to iterate over the array, and you can simply use the `.push()` method to easily append a string to your array.

```js
var inputName = document.getElementById("input");
var cityArray = [];


function submit() {
  cityArray.push(inputName.value);
  console.log(cityArray);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="text" id="input" />
  <button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
  <div id="placeholder"></div>
</body>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you add more than just the code? I personally feel "Hope this helps" is not enough.

Comment: I am just editing it. Including explanations! thanks!

Comment: Both of the provided answers work, but this one has more info. So, up-voted and verified as accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: @VladimirJovanović you are very welcome. If I may ask you to mark the answer as accepted, so future visitors can solve their issues faster? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to use `.push()` method it will add the new entered `string` to the `array`, without the need to iterate it:

```
function submit() {
   cityArray.push(inputName.value);

}
```

And you need to initialize your array as an empty array with `[]` :

```
var cityArray = [];
```

And you don't need to create the `submit` function in the `body.onload` event handler because it won't be accessible outside of it and may lead for an error.

**Demo:**

```js
var inputName = document.getElementById("input");
var cityArray = [];


function submit() {
  cityArray.push(inputName.value);
  console.log(cityArray);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" />
<button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
<div id="placeholder"></div>
```

Comment: Ok, I'll do that. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, that helped. It works now. Up-voted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Js Code

```
//declare your array like this
var yourArray = new Array();
//To add items to array:
yourArray.push(yourString);
//To get you can use indexing like(almost any other language)
yourArray[i]
//You can even set as an object array like this:
yourArray.push({
  text: 'blablabla'
})
//So, in your case, filling up the array could be something like this:
var inputText = document.getElementById('input').value;
yourArray.push(inputText);
// show it
for (var i = 0; i < yourArray.length; i++) {
  alert(yourArray[i]);
}
```

> HTML Script

```
<body>
  <input type="text" id="input" />
  <button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
  <div id="placeholder"></div>
</body>
```